# Android App Screen Compatibility Issue

Tags: android, android-screen-support

I have always issue with screen compatibility, i am creating one layout for all type screen. I am using all 5 type mipmap/drawable for images. 
The issue is when i ask to my designer for icons they are asking me for size. i am following below link for all type images
https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Still not getting correct icons for all type screens.

```
36x36 (0.75x) for low-density
48x48 (1.0x baseline) for medium-density
72x72 (1.5x) for high-density
96x96 (2.0x) for extra-high-density
144x144 (3.0x) for extra-extra-high-density
192x192 (4.0x) for extra-extra-extra-high-density
```

those size looking big in phones.
It would be very much helpful if anybody can specify the size for different screens.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android Studio gives those features where you can create all 5 different size icons.You need to follow below step:

1. right click on drawable then >new >Image Asset>

[image]

[image]

2. From 2nd image select image option and select your icon from desktop/laptop and android studio will generate all 5 mipmap/drawable type icons.

you can also try with this link

https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html

Happy Coding!!

Answer (score 1):

This way you are creating icons with size 48dp x 48dp - they are big. I suppose you want 24dp x 24dp (that is 24px x 24px for medium-density).
Do you know this tool? 
https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html

And be sure to put those icons in correct folder...
medium-density in drawable-mdpi, high-density in drawable-hdpi and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to import icon is using image assets:

right click on drawable then >new >Image Asset>the by selecting image type and image location you can easily add icons :)

make sure this should be used in case of icons only